# How to substract between two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm going to subtract the sum of values with same ID in a column with the corresponding value of another column (these have identical data). If the value in column AMT is only one time to do only the difference.

So I want the difference between AMT (table A) and AMT (table B), which have the same ID, CRD, STN and different TYPE.

Table A:

```
AMT     ID      CRD     STN     TYPE
------- ------- ------- ------- ----
22000   7123344 556677  442233  0200
22000   7123344 556677  442233  0200
22000   7123344 556677  442233  0200
11500   7132323 992211  556611  0200
10000   7132323 992211  556611  0200
35200   7199933 223344  989898  0200
```

Table B:

```
AMT     ID      CRD     STN     TYPE
------- ------- ------- ------- ----
67000   7123344 556677  442233  0220
20000   7132323 992211  556611  0220
35300   7199933 223344  989898  0220
```

The result that I want to get:

```
DIFF
----
1000
-1500
100
```

Comment: It will be a pretty basic query doing a join and group by to accomplish this.  Have you written much SQL?

Comment: You should really show what you've tried and why it doesn't work. Why is the third difference 100 - which ID is that supposed to be for? And do you need a difference for the data that's only in one of (either) table? And the absolute value of the differences (in your example, one of the first two is positive the other is negative)?

Comment: I corrected it. Regards,

Comment: @AlexPoole Can u give me a suggestion because i've edited the table with correst result. I tried this query but the result that i get is: -22000;-22000;-22000;-11500;-10000;-35200. So the correct should be: DIFF
----
1000
-1500
100 All records are values i didn't have any value "0" or null.

Comment: @AlexPoole   I've edited it, Sorry! Can u have any suggestion please? Kind Regards,

Comment: @Denada.Dx - I've added a demo to my answer showing that it gets the numbers you expect with that modified sample data. I can't tell what you're doing differently, but if you get those answers then either ID/CRD/STN don't match, or TYPE does match, between the two tables. (If you have an issue with an answer you should comment on that, rather than the question).

Comment: @AlexPoole But I've more values then i've presented. So they may be 2000-3000 records. Can u give me a help? ID,CRD,STN match are the same, as i edited .

Comment: Help with what? The answer I gave works for the data you showed. Your previous comment seems to say it doesn't work for that data. I can't see any reason that it wouldn't work with other data that matches the rules you described in the question - same ID, CRD, STN and different TYPE. The number of records don't matter, its whether they match. Obviously I can't see all of your data so can't tell where you've gone wrong, or why you think the result you get is wrong.

Comment: @AlexPoole Dear Alex, Thank you for your response it worked as well with Inner join. Have a nice day!

Comment: @AlexPoole How can i add a condition clause entry group by?

Answer (score 2):

Your sample output doesn't really match the table data; if we can just ignore the `100` value then you probably want something like this (giving table data in CTEs):

```
with table_a (AMT, ID, CRD, STN, TYPE) as (
            select 22000, 7123344, 556677, 442233, 0200 from dual
  union all select 22000, 7123344, 556677, 442233, 0200 from dual
  union all select 22000, 7123344, 556677, 442233, 0200 from dual
  union all select 11500, 7132323, 992211, 556611, 0200 from dual
  union all select 10000, 7132323, 992211, 556611, 0200 from dual
  union all select 35200, 7178866, 223344, 989898, 0200 from dual
),
table_b (AMT, ID, CRD, STN, TYPE) as (
            select 67000, 7123344, 556677, 442233, 0220 from dual
  union all select 20000, 7132323, 992211, 556611, 0220 from dual
  union all select 67100, 7199933, 667733, 343433, 0220 from dual
)
select a.id, a.crd, a.stn, a.sum_amt, b.sum_amt, a.sum_amt - b.sum_amt as diff
from (
  select id, crd, stn, type, sum(amt) as sum_amt
  from table_a
  group by id, crd, stn, type
) a
inner join (
  select id, crd, stn, type, sum(amt) as sum_amt
  from table_b
  group by id, crd, stn, type
) b
on b.id = a.id and b.crd = a.crd and b.stn = a.stn and b.type != a.type
order by a.id, a.crd, a.stn;

        ID        CRD        STN    SUM_AMT    SUM_AMT       DIFF
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
   7123344     556677     442233      66000      67000      -1000
   7132323     992211     556611      21500      20000       1500
```

The subqueries (inline views) generate the sums for each ID/CRD/STN/TYPE, and those are then joined together so the equivalent sums can be subtracted. Even so, your result has both as positive numbers; if that is what you want then you can just modify it to do

```
abs(a.sum_amt - b.sum_amt) as diff
```

or you might want the subtraction to go the other way, so you get +1000 and -1500.

It's possible you also want the difference for combinations that only in exist in table A:

```
select a.id, a.crd, a.stn, a.sum_amt, b.sum_amt,
  coalesce(a.sum_amt, 0) - coalesce(b.sum_amt, 0) as diff
from (
  select id, crd, stn, type, sum(amt) as sum_amt
  from table_a
  group by id, crd, stn, type
) a
left outer join (
  select id, crd, stn, type, sum(amt) as sum_amt
  from table_b
  group by id, crd, stn, type
) b
on b.id = a.id and b.crd = a.crd and b.stn = a.stn and b.type != a.type
order by a.id, a.crd, a.stn;

        ID        CRD        STN    SUM_AMT    SUM_AMT       DIFF
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
   7123344     556677     442233      66000      67000      -1000
   7132323     992211     556611      21500      20000       1500
   7178866     223344     989898      35200                 35200
```

or for combinations that appear in either table A or table B or both:

```
select coalesce(a.id, b.id) as id, coalesce(a.crd, b.crd) as crd,
  coalesce(a.stn, b.stn) as stn, a.sum_amt, b.sum_amt,
  coalesce(a.sum_amt, 0) - coalesce(b.sum_amt, 0) as diff
from (
  select id, crd, stn, type, sum(amt) as sum_amt
  from table_a
  group by id, crd, stn, type
) a
full outer join (
  select id, crd, stn, type, sum(amt) as sum_amt
  from table_b
  group by id, crd, stn, type
) b
on b.id = a.id and b.crd = a.crd and b.stn = a.stn and b.type != a.type
order by coalesce(a.id, b.id), coalesce(a.crd, b.crd), coalesce(a.stn, b.stn);

        ID        CRD        STN    SUM_AMT    SUM_AMT       DIFF
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
   7123344     556677     442233      66000      67000      -1000
   7132323     992211     556611      21500      20000       1500
   7178866     223344     989898      35200                 35200
   7199933     667733     343433                 67100     -67100
```

These use left or full outer joins, and add `coalesce()` calls to deal with data that doesn't exist in one inline view or the other.

---

With your modified data, and reversing the calculation to get the sign you want, this gets the result you expected:

```
with table_a (AMT, ID, CRD, STN, TYPE) as (
            select 22000, 7123344, 556677, 442233, 0200 from dual
  union all select 22000, 7123344, 556677, 442233, 0200 from dual
  union all select 22000, 7123344, 556677, 442233, 0200 from dual
  union all select 11500, 7132323, 992211, 556611, 0200 from dual
  union all select 10000, 7132323, 992211, 556611, 0200 from dual
  union all select 35200, 7199933, 223344, 989898, 0200 from dual
),
table_b (AMT, ID, CRD, STN, TYPE) as (
            select 67000, 7123344, 556677, 442233, 0220 from dual
  union all select 20000, 7132323, 992211, 556611, 0220 from dual
  union all select 35300, 7199933, 223344, 989898, 0220 from dual
)
select a.id, a.crd, a.stn, a.sum_amt, b.sum_amt, b.sum_amt - a.sum_amt as diff
from (
  select id, crd, stn, type, sum(amt) as sum_amt
  from table_a
  group by id, crd, stn, type
) a
inner join (
  select id, crd, stn, type, sum(amt) as sum_amt
  from table_b
  group by id, crd, stn, type
) b
on b.id = a.id and b.crd = a.crd and b.stn = a.stn and b.type != a.type
order by a.id, a.crd, a.stn;

        ID        CRD        STN    SUM_AMT    SUM_AMT       DIFF
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
   7123344     556677     442233      66000      67000       1000
   7132323     992211     556611      21500      20000      -1500
   7199933     223344     989898      35200      35300        100
```